# Upload Base64 image with Firebase 3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage

It is possible to upload base64 image to Firebase ?

I have tried this code :

```
                    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
                console.log(storageRef);                                        
                var file = "data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64.....";

                var uploadTask = storageRef.child('avatars/'+user.providerData[0].uid+'/photo-'+$scope.number+'.jpg').put(file);
                uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
                }, function(error) {
                  console.log('error');
                }, function() {
                  console.log('success');
                  var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                });
```

But i have an error :

```
{code: "storage/invalid-argument", message: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse: null, name: "FirebaseError"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the base64 into a function that returns a blob such as this:

```
base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        var sliceSize = 1024;
        var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
        var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
        var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
        var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

        for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
            var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
            var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

            var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
            for (var offset = begin, i = 0 ; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
                bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
            }
            byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
        }
        return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You only need to use the **putString** function without converting the BASE64 to blob.

```
firebase.storage().ref('/your/path/here').child('file_name')
.putString(your_base64_image, ‘base64’, {contentType:’image/jpg’});
```

Make sure to pass the metadata **{contentType:’image/jpg’}** as ***the third parameter*** (optional) to the function putString in order for you to retrieve the data in an image format.

or simply put:

```
uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref('/your/path/here').child('file_name').putString(image, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpg'});
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
  function(snapshot) {
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}, function() {
  // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
  var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
});
```

You can then use the **downloadURL** to save to firebase.database() and/or to put as an src to an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Storage takes the JS [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) or [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) types, rather than a string. You can store your base64 encoded data in a file and then upload it, though I recommend converting them to a "real" file (`jpg` or `png` judging on it looks like a photo) so you can have a content type, have browsers treat it as such, get benefits like compression, etc.